# Heroku rejecting my git push due to SQLite3

Tags: ruby-on-rails, heroku, sqlite

Heroku keeps rejecting my pushes with this error:

```
 Make sure that `gem install sqlite3 -v '1.3.11'` succeeds before bundling.
remote:  !
remote:  !     Failed to install gems via Bundler.
remote:  !     
remote:  !     Detected sqlite3 gem which is not supported on Heroku.
remote:  !     https://devcenter.heroku.com/articles/sqlite3
remote:  !
remote:  !     Push rejected, failed to compile Ruby app.
```

I realize this is a common problem (I have looked at other threads) I have tried removing the sqlite3 gem from my Gemfile, I ran a bundle install and made sure that the sqlite3 gem was also out of my Gemfile.lock (which it was).
I also got rid of all references to sqlite3 from my database.yml and replaced them with Postgres:

```
#
default: &default
  adapter: postgresql
  encoding: unicode
  database: store_development
  pool: 5
  timeout: 5000

development:
    adapter: postgresql
    encoding: unicode
    database: store_development

# Warning: The database defined as "test" will be erased and
# re-generated from your development database when you run "rake".
# Do not set this db to the same as development or production.
test:
  adapter: postgresql
  encoding: unicode
  database: store_test

production:
  adapter: postgresql
  encoding: unicode
  database: store_development
```

I'm lost any suggestions?

Here is my gemfile:

source 'https://rubygems.org'

```
# Bundle edge Rails instead: gem 'rails', github: 'rails/rails'
gem 'rails', '4.2.5.1'
# Use SCSS for stylesheets
gem 'sass-rails', '~> 5.0'
# Use Uglifier as compressor for JavaScript assets
gem 'uglifier', '>= 1.3.0'
# Use CoffeeScript for .coffee assets and views
gem 'coffee-rails', '~> 4.1.0'
#bcrypt for for encrpytion
gem 'bcrypt', '~> 3.1', '>= 3.1.11'
#byebug
gem 'byebug', '~> 9.0', '>= 9.0.5'
# Use jquery as the JavaScript library
gem 'jquery-rails'
# Turbolinks makes following links in your web application faster. Read more: https://github.com/rails/turbolinks
gem 'turbolinks'
# Build JSON APIs with ease. Read more: https://github.com/rails/jbuilder
gem 'jbuilder', '~> 2.0'
# bundle exec rake doc:rails generates the API under doc/api.
gem 'sdoc', '~> 0.4.0', group: :doc
#paperclip for easy upload management
gem 'paperclip', '~> 4.3', '>= 4.3.6'
#bootstrap-sass
gem 'bootstrap-sass', '~> 3.3', '>= 3.3.6'
#searchkick
gem 'searchkick', '~> 1.2', '>= 1.2.1'
#paginate
gem 'will_paginate', '~> 3.1'
#paginate for bootstrap
gem 'bootstrap-will_paginate', '~> 0.0.10'
#Carrierwave
#gem 'carrierwave'
#Cloudinary
#gem 'cloudinary'
#Paperclip forcloudinary
gem 'paperclip-cloudinary'
#elasticsearch stuff
gem 'elasticsearch-rails'
gem 'elasticsearch-model'
#bonsi
gem 'bonsai-elasticsearch-rails', '~> 0.0.4'



group :development, :test do


end

group :development do
  # Access an IRB console on exception pages or by using <%= console %> in views
  gem 'web-console', '~> 2.0'
  # Spring speeds up development by keeping your application running in the background. Read more: https://github.com/rails/spring
  gem 'spring'
  #db stuff
  gem 'sqlite3'



end
group :production do
  gem 'rails_12factor'
  gem 'puma', '~> 3.4'
  #postgresql
  gem 'pg'
end
```

I'll also include the whole Heroku rejection just for reference:

```
    remote: Compressing source files... done.
remote: Building source:
remote: 
remote: -----> Ruby app detected
remote: -----> Compiling Ruby/Rails
remote: -----> Using Ruby version: ruby-2.2.4
remote: -----> Installing dependencies using bundler 1.11.2
remote:        Running: bundle install --without development:test --path vendor/bundle --binstubs vendor/bundle/bin -j4 --deployment
remote:        Warning: the running version of Bundler is older than the version that created the lockfile. We suggest you upgrade to the latest version of Bundler by running `gem install bundler`.
remote:        Fetching gem metadata from https://rubygems.org/.........
remote:        Fetching version metadata from https://rubygems.org/...
remote:        Fetching dependency metadata from https://rubygems.org/..
remote:        Using i18n 0.7.0
remote:        Using rake 11.1.2
remote:        Using json 1.8.3
remote:        Using minitest 5.8.4
remote:        Using thread_safe 0.3.5
remote:        Using builder 3.2.2
remote:        Using erubis 2.7.0
remote:        Using mini_portile2 2.0.0
remote:        Using rack 1.6.4
remote:        Using mime-types-data 3.2016.0221
remote:        Using arel 6.0.3
remote:        Using execjs 2.6.0
remote:        Using aws_cf_signer 0.1.3
remote:        Using bcrypt 3.1.11
remote:        Using bonsai-elasticsearch-rails 0.0.4
remote:        Using sass 3.4.22
remote:        Using will_paginate 3.1.0
remote:        Using coffee-script-source 1.10.0
remote:        Using thor 0.19.1
remote:        Using concurrent-ruby 1.0.1
remote:        Using orm_adapter 0.5.0
remote:        Using multi_json 1.11.2
remote:        Using multipart-post 2.0.0
remote:        Using hashie 3.4.3
remote:        Using elasticsearch-rails 0.1.9
remote:        Using mimemagic 0.3.0
remote:        Using pg 0.18.4
remote:        Using bundler 1.11.2
remote:        Using rails_serve_static_assets 0.0.5
remote:        Using rails_stdout_logging 0.0.5
remote:        Using tilt 2.0.2
remote:        Using rdoc 4.2.2
remote:        Using tzinfo 1.2.2
remote:        Using nokogiri 1.6.7.2
remote:        Using mime-types 3.0
remote:        Using autoprefixer-rails 6.3.6
remote:        Using uglifier 3.0.0
remote:        Using rack-test 0.6.3
remote:        Using warden 1.2.6
remote:        Using bootstrap-will_paginate 0.0.10
remote:        Using coffee-script 2.4.1
remote:        Using sprockets 3.6.0
remote:        Using elasticsearch-api 1.0.17
remote:        Using faraday 0.9.2
remote:        Using rails_12factor 0.0.3
remote:        Using sdoc 0.4.1
remote:        Using activesupport 4.2.5.1
remote:        Using loofah 2.0.3
remote:        Using mail 2.6.4
remote:        Using rest-client 1.6.7
remote:        Using bootstrap-sass 3.3.6
remote:        Using elasticsearch-transport 1.0.17
remote:        Using rails-deprecated_sanitizer 1.0.3
remote:        Using globalid 0.3.6
remote:        Using activemodel 4.2.5.1
remote:        Using climate_control 0.0.3
remote:        Using jbuilder 2.4.1
remote:        Using rails-html-sanitizer 1.0.3
remote:        Using cloudinary 1.2.0
remote:        Using rails-dom-testing 1.0.7
remote:        Using elasticsearch 1.0.17
remote:        Using activejob 4.2.5.1
remote:        Using cocaine 0.5.8
remote:        Using paperclip-cloudinary 1.1.0
remote:        Using actionview 4.2.5.1
remote:        Using elasticsearch-model 0.1.9
remote:        Using activerecord 4.2.5.1
remote:        Using searchkick 1.2.1
remote:        Using paperclip 4.3.6
remote:        Using actionpack 4.2.5.1
remote:        Using actionmailer 4.2.5.1
remote:        Using railties 4.2.5.1
remote:        Using sprockets-rails 3.0.4
remote:        Using coffee-rails 4.1.1
remote:        Using responders 2.1.2
remote:        Using jquery-rails 4.1.1
remote:        Using rails 4.2.5.1
remote:        Using sass-rails 5.0.4
remote:        Using turbolinks 2.5.3
remote:        Using devise 4.0.0
remote:        Installing sqlite3 1.3.11 with native extensions
remote:        Gem::Ext::BuildError: ERROR: Failed to build gem native extension.
remote:        /tmp/build_650c9daea9707f0830f7e2ecbfc558e2/vendor/ruby-2.2.4/bin/ruby -r ./siteconf20160801-197-lz2bsz.rb extconf.rb
remote:        checking for sqlite3.h... no
remote:        sqlite3.h is missing. Try 'port install sqlite3 +universal',
remote:        'yum install sqlite-devel' or 'apt-get install libsqlite3-dev'
remote:        and check your shared library search path (the
remote:        location where your sqlite3 shared library is located).
remote:        *** extconf.rb failed ***
remote:        Could not create Makefile due to some reason, probably lack of necessary
remote:        libraries and/or headers.  Check the mkmf.log file for more details.  You may
remote:        need configuration options.
remote:        Provided configuration options:
remote:        --with-opt-dir
remote:        --without-opt-dir
remote:        --with-opt-include
remote:        --without-opt-include=${opt-dir}/include
remote:        --with-opt-lib
remote:        --without-opt-lib=${opt-dir}/lib
remote:        --with-make-prog
remote:        --without-make-prog
remote:        --srcdir=.
remote:        --curdir
remote:        --ruby=/tmp/build_650c9daea9707f0830f7e2ecbfc558e2/vendor/ruby-2.2.4/bin/$(RUBY_BASE_NAME)
remote:        --with-sqlite3-dir
remote:        --without-sqlite3-dir
remote:        --with-sqlite3-include
remote:        --without-sqlite3-include=${sqlite3-dir}/include
remote:        --with-sqlite3-lib
remote:        --without-sqlite3-lib=${sqlite3-dir}/lib
remote:        extconf failed, exit code 1
remote:        Gem files will remain installed in /tmp/build_650c9daea9707f0830f7e2ecbfc558e2/vendor/bundle/ruby/2.2.0/gems/sqlite3-1.3.11 for inspection.
remote:        Results logged to /tmp/build_650c9daea9707f0830f7e2ecbfc558e2/vendor/bundle/ruby/2.2.0/extensions/x86_64-linux/2.2.0-static/sqlite3-1.3.11/gem_make.out
remote:        An error occurred while installing sqlite3 (1.3.11), and Bundler cannot
remote:        continue.
remote:        Make sure that `gem install sqlite3 -v '1.3.11'` succeeds before bundling.
remote:        Bundler Output: Warning: the running version of Bundler is older than the version that created the lockfile. We suggest you upgrade to the latest version of Bundler by running `gem install bundler`.
remote:        Fetching gem metadata from https://rubygems.org/.........
remote:        Fetching version metadata from https://rubygems.org/...
remote:        Fetching dependency metadata from https://rubygems.org/..
remote:        Using i18n 0.7.0
remote:        Using rake 11.1.2
remote:        Using json 1.8.3
remote:        Using minitest 5.8.4
remote:        Using thread_safe 0.3.5
remote:        Using builder 3.2.2
remote:        Using erubis 2.7.0
remote:        Using mini_portile2 2.0.0
remote:        Using rack 1.6.4
remote:        Using mime-types-data 3.2016.0221
remote:        Using arel 6.0.3
remote:        Using execjs 2.6.0
remote:        Using aws_cf_signer 0.1.3
remote:        Using bcrypt 3.1.11
remote:        Using bonsai-elasticsearch-rails 0.0.4
remote:        Using sass 3.4.22
remote:        Using will_paginate 3.1.0
remote:        Using coffee-script-source 1.10.0
remote:        Using thor 0.19.1
remote:        Using concurrent-ruby 1.0.1
remote:        Using orm_adapter 0.5.0
remote:        Using multi_json 1.11.2
remote:        Using multipart-post 2.0.0
remote:        Using hashie 3.4.3
remote:        Using elasticsearch-rails 0.1.9
remote:        Using mimemagic 0.3.0
remote:        Using pg 0.18.4
remote:        Using bundler 1.11.2
remote:        Using rails_serve_static_assets 0.0.5
remote:        Using rails_stdout_logging 0.0.5
remote:        Using tilt 2.0.2
remote:        Using rdoc 4.2.2
remote:        Using tzinfo 1.2.2
remote:        Using nokogiri 1.6.7.2
remote:        Using mime-types 3.0
remote:        Using autoprefixer-rails 6.3.6
remote:        Using uglifier 3.0.0
remote:        Using rack-test 0.6.3
remote:        Using warden 1.2.6
remote:        Using bootstrap-will_paginate 0.0.10
remote:        Using coffee-script 2.4.1
remote:        Using sprockets 3.6.0
remote:        Using elasticsearch-api 1.0.17
remote:        Using faraday 0.9.2
remote:        Using rails_12factor 0.0.3
remote:        Using sdoc 0.4.1
remote:        Using activesupport 4.2.5.1
remote:        Using loofah 2.0.3
remote:        Using mail 2.6.4
remote:        Using rest-client 1.6.7
remote:        Using bootstrap-sass 3.3.6
remote:        Using elasticsearch-transport 1.0.17
remote:        Using rails-deprecated_sanitizer 1.0.3
remote:        Using globalid 0.3.6
remote:        Using activemodel 4.2.5.1
remote:        Using climate_control 0.0.3
remote:        Using jbuilder 2.4.1
remote:        Using rails-html-sanitizer 1.0.3
remote:        Using cloudinary 1.2.0
remote:        Using rails-dom-testing 1.0.7
remote:        Using elasticsearch 1.0.17
remote:        Using activejob 4.2.5.1
remote:        Using cocaine 0.5.8
remote:        Using paperclip-cloudinary 1.1.0
remote:        Using actionview 4.2.5.1
remote:        Using elasticsearch-model 0.1.9
remote:        Using activerecord 4.2.5.1
remote:        Using searchkick 1.2.1
remote:        Using paperclip 4.3.6
remote:        Using actionpack 4.2.5.1
remote:        Using actionmailer 4.2.5.1
remote:        Using railties 4.2.5.1
remote:        Using sprockets-rails 3.0.4
remote:        Using coffee-rails 4.1.1
remote:        Using responders 2.1.2
remote:        Using jquery-rails 4.1.1
remote:        Using rails 4.2.5.1
remote:        Using sass-rails 5.0.4
remote:        Using turbolinks 2.5.3
remote:        Using devise 4.0.0
remote:        Installing sqlite3 1.3.11 with native extensions
remote:        
remote:        Gem::Ext::BuildError: ERROR: Failed to build gem native extension.
remote:        
remote:        /tmp/build_650c9daea9707f0830f7e2ecbfc558e2/vendor/ruby-2.2.4/bin/ruby -r ./siteconf20160801-197-lz2bsz.rb extconf.rb
remote:        checking for sqlite3.h... no
remote:        sqlite3.h is missing. Try 'port install sqlite3 +universal',
remote:        'yum install sqlite-devel' or 'apt-get install libsqlite3-dev'
remote:        and check your shared library search path (the
remote:        location where your sqlite3 shared library is located).
remote:        *** extconf.rb failed ***
remote:        Could not create Makefile due to some reason, probably lack of necessary
remote:        libraries and/or headers.  Check the mkmf.log file for more details.  You may
remote:        need configuration options.
remote:        
remote:        Provided configuration options:
remote:        --with-opt-dir
remote:        --without-opt-dir
remote:        --with-opt-include
remote:        --without-opt-include=${opt-dir}/include
remote:        --with-opt-lib
remote:        --without-opt-lib=${opt-dir}/lib
remote:        --with-make-prog
remote:        --without-make-prog
remote:        --srcdir=.
remote:        --curdir
remote:        --ruby=/tmp/build_650c9daea9707f0830f7e2ecbfc558e2/vendor/ruby-2.2.4/bin/$(RUBY_BASE_NAME)
remote:        --with-sqlite3-dir
remote:        --without-sqlite3-dir
remote:        --with-sqlite3-include
remote:        --without-sqlite3-include=${sqlite3-dir}/include
remote:        --with-sqlite3-lib
remote:        --without-sqlite3-lib=${sqlite3-dir}/lib
remote:        
remote:        extconf failed, exit code 1
remote:        
remote:        Gem files will remain installed in /tmp/build_650c9daea9707f0830f7e2ecbfc558e2/vendor/bundle/ruby/2.2.0/gems/sqlite3-1.3.11 for inspection.
remote:        Results logged to /tmp/build_650c9daea9707f0830f7e2ecbfc558e2/vendor/bundle/ruby/2.2.0/extensions/x86_64-linux/2.2.0-static/sqlite3-1.3.11/gem_make.out
remote:        An error occurred while installing sqlite3 (1.3.11), and Bundler cannot
remote:        continue.
remote:        Make sure that `gem install sqlite3 -v '1.3.11'` succeeds before bundling.
remote:  !
remote:  !     Failed to install gems via Bundler.
remote:  !     
remote:  !     Detected sqlite3 gem which is not supported on Heroku.
remote:  !     https://devcenter.heroku.com/articles/sqlite3
remote:  !
remote:  !     Push rejected, failed to compile Ruby app.
remote: 
remote:  !     Push failed
remote: Verifying deploy...
remote: 
remote: !   Push rejected to professor-ratings.
remote:
```

Could the problem be with the build configuration?  How can I change that?'

Comment: Can you show your Gemfile please? Try to delete Gemfile.lock first, then do bundle and commit. I had issues with spring because it was not only on development.

Comment: Now showing gemfile.

Comment: you did try to delete file Gemfile.lock first, then bundle then commit the lock file...? right?

Comment: I just tried that, got rid of the Gemfile.lock, then committed it.  Before pushing it to Heroku I made sure to run: 'heroku config:set BUNDLE_WITHOUT="development:test"'  just for good measure.

Answer (score 4):

Using SQLITE3 is fine in development, Heroku just needs PG for production, your gemfile should look something like this:

```
group :development, :test do
    gem 'sqlite3'
end

group :production do
    gem 'pg'
end
```

You may need to reset your database (rails db:reset / rake db:reset depending on rails version). Then you can just run bundle install --without production

Comment: My gemfile looks like what you suggested, I ran a bundle install and I'm still getting the same error message. I even did a db:reset.

Comment: Move gem 'sqlite3' in to the group :development, :test section, then run:
`heroku config:set BUNDLE_WITHOUT="development:test"` then run bundle install and try push to heroku master.

Comment: Still getting the same error :(  I'll keep fiddling with this, does my database.yml look ok?  Would that be causing any problems?

Comment: You could maybe try reverting back to the original database.yml file, I'm not sure if this is automatically modified once pushed to production (I set up an empty project setting the production database to postgresql and it didn't change the database.yml file. Could you run `heroku run rake db:migrate` and see if this does anything?

Comment: Migrating the db on Heroku seems to work fine however when I try to then push to  Heroku it fails same problem.  Could the problem be with the configuration:  remote:        Provided configuration options:
remote:        --without-make-prog
remote:        --with-sqlite3-dir
remote:        --without-sqlite3-dir
remote:        --with-sqlite3-include
remote:        --with-sqlite3-lib

Answer (score 1):

**I had the same problem, I achieve FIXED**

1. Delete file "gemfile.lock"
2. Move "gem 'sqlite3'" into development group.
3. Add production group whit gem 'pg':

   ```
   group :production do
     gem 'pg'
   end
   ```
4. then bundle
5. git add .
6. In console or command promt or CMD run:

   heroku config:set BUNDLE_WITHOUT="development:test"
7. Dont forget commit.
8. And then, git push heroku master

**GO SUCCESS!!**

Answer (score 0):

```
remote:  !     Detected sqlite3 gem which is not supported on Heroku.
remote:  !     https://devcenter.heroku.com/articles/sqlite3
```

Log it self say's sqlite3 is not supported on Heroku by default. by default Heroku use the `postgres` database.

Make sure your `Gemfile` contains `gem 'pg'` in `production group` and try again, it will surely work.

If you want to use `sqlite3` on `developmet` then you have to do code as below in your `Gemfile`

```
#Gemfile
gem 'sqlite3', group: [:development, :test]
gem 'pg', group: :production
```

Answer (score 0):

Firstly makes sure you have added the following gems

```
group :development, :test do
    gem 'sqlite3'
end

group :production do
    gem 'pg'
end
```

Next make sure you run `bundle intsall`

Now push your app to github `git push origin master`

Now your ready to push it into production `git push heroku master`

After you bundle install you need to make sure you pushed your app to github first (assuming your using github)

Answer (score 0):

As they said you need to replace the gem, however gem pg won't work on windows because the latest version is buggy. So you need to do three things basically to push correctly to heroku. 
1- add these two gems to your gemfile

```
    group :production do 
gem 'pg','~>0.19.0.pre20160409114042'
gem 'rails_12factor'
```

the group is only if you want to keep pg in the production mode mainly then of  course run

```
bundle install
```

so make sure everything is alright by running the server once more all the gems are ok now we move to the next step 
2- make sure you are on the right heroku and apparently you are but here is the a nice trick you can do

```
rake assets:precompile
```

to make sure all your assets are compiled and ready then do the normal git procedure

```
git add .
git commit -am"latest or whatever you feel like"
```

3- last but not least push to heroku the right way

```
git push heroku master
```

You pushed to heroku but your database didn't run on heroku right

```
heroku run rails db:migrate
```

So now it should be all good to go.

If it's still not ok please tell us. 
Hope that's helpful

Comment: Thanks for your help, unfortunately this did not work for me.  I did this and I still get the exact same error:     `  extconf failed, exit code 1          Gem files will remain installed in... ... for inspection.
   Results logged to... 
     ...An error occurred while installing sqlite3 (1.3.11), and Bundler 
      Make sure that gem install sqlite3 -v '1.3.11' succeeds before bundling.
     Failed to install gems via Bundler.
   Detected sqlite3 gem which is not supported on Heroku.
   https://devcenter.heroku.com/articles/sqlite3
     Push rejected...`

Comment: Also I'm on OSX so I don't know if Postgres's latest version will have the same problems.

Comment: Hi buddy but this means you are still using sqlite.try removing it all from the gemfile and rerun the bundle. Make sure you ran bundle install properly and the gem was installed. I think pg gem version wont make a problem if youre on osx. Its always a good idea to work on postgresql from the begining if you are planning to deploy on heroku.

Comment: I removed every SQLite gem from the gemfile, even in the development environment.  Ran a bundle install and seemed to work, ran a rake assets:precompile at first I got an error that said sqlite3 was the db adapter and was not loaded, so I changed the db adapter to postgresql then it worked fine (the precompile).  Committed it and pushed it to Heroku got the same error message.

Comment: Did you run heroku rails db:migrate ?

Comment: Yes I ran heroku run db:migrate and that worked (the db:migration) however  the problem is not with the database running on heroku (at least I haven't had that problem yet) the the problem is that I can't push to heroku I keep getting that error message every time I try to push and then it fails.  The heroku logs online just say "build failed"

Comment: Are yoy sure that you are on the heroku branch ?? Git heroku branch. That would be a very small mistake

Comment: I'm pretty sure when it fails the error message ends with: Push rejected to professor-ratings.
remote: 
To https://git.heroku.com/professor-ratings.git
 ! [remote rejected] master -> master (pre-receive hook declined)
error: failed to push some refs to 'https://git.heroku.com/professor-ratings.git'

Comment: Try heroku logs and see exactly what it says because I think that this means either you are not logged in your heroku or this http isnt the same as the one you created.

Comment: I don't think so because I'm able to rake the Heroku DB and do other things the error is very specific and seems to relate to SQLite:  extconf failed, 
       An error occurred while installing sqlite3 (1.3.11), and Bundler cannot
       continue.
       Make sure that `gem install sqlite3 -v '1.3.11'` succeeds before bundling.
 !
 !     Failed to install gems via Bundler.
 !     Detected sqlite3 gem which is not supported on Heroku.
 !     https://devcenter.heroku.com/articles/sqlite3
 !     Push rejected, failed to compile Ruby app.
 !     Push failed